# Can I have record as a parameter in INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, data-warehouse

I'm trying to populate a new table T.

```
create or replace procedure extractData 
is

cursor c1 is
SELECT a.id,a.data,b.id,b.data,c.id,c.data
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
LEFT JOIN c on b.id=c.id;

begin
for currRec in c1
loop
insert into table T
values currRec,(select a_seq.nextval from dual),(select b_seq.nextval from dual),(select b_seq.nextval from dual),SYSDATE
end loop
```

Will this give me a table with columns from currRec then the sequences and SYSDATE? Also is there a better way to do this without making it more messy than it already is? In the real table, I have about 10 'data' columns in a,b and c each so I'm worried about something screwing up or going out of order. I'm writing a procedure for a data warehouse that takes in data from three different sources and combines them in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT
INTO    table
SELECT  a.id, a.data, b.id, b.data, c.id, c.data,
        a_seq.nextval, b_seq.nextval, c_seq.nextval,
        SYSDATE
FROM    a
LEFT JOIN
        b
ON      b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN
        c
ON      c.id = b.id
```

Comment: I might need to do some processing that's why I used a cursor. But in cases that I don't, I'd like to know if I can add it like I mentioned above.I don't have oracle 11g so I don't think I can call nextval without doing a select from dual either.

Comment: @user3786548 - you can use `seq.NEXTVAL` without doing a `SELECT...FROM DUAL` starting with 10g. [There are some limitations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm) but I don't think they apply in this case. Share and enjoy.

Comment: We have *always* been able to use `a_seq.nextval` in SQL statements.  We couldn't do variable assignment in PL/SQL without selecting from DUAL, prior to 11g.